# Different ways to test for $1 after regex?

Tags: regex, perl

Normally when I check if the regex succeeded I do

```
if ($var =~ /aaa(\d+)bbb(\d+)/) { # $1 and $2 should be defined now }
```

but I recall seeing a variation of this that seamed shorter. Perhaps it was only with one buffer.

Can anyone think or other ways to test if `$1` after a successful regex?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can avoid $1 and similar altogether:

```
if (my ($anum, $bnum) = $var =~ /aaa(\d+)bbb(\d+)/) {
    # Work with $anum and $bnum
}
```

Comment: +1 so much. Avoiding side-effects is best! `$1` unintentionally changing is a frequent source of bugs.

Answer (score 1):

The only shorter way that I can think of is if the match is on $_. So for instance:

```
for (@strings) {
   if (m/aaa(\d+)bbb(\d+)/) {
...
```

If the match succeeds then $1 and $2 will be populated.

Comment: Shorter isn't better, especially if there are loops inside of loops.

Answer (score 1):

never forget about

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

I like plain syntax in Perl, but not in this way:

```
my $str = 'abc101abc';

$str =~ m/(\d+)/ and do {print $1;}
```

OR

```
$str =~ m/(\d+)/ and print $1;
```

OR

```
($str in $_, so $_ = $str;)

m/(\d+)/ and print $1;
```

BUT! `TIMTOWTDI` helps you to dream about your own style :)

I prefer old-if style.

Answer (score 0):

Reading both answers, I now recall that this was what I had seen

```
my $str = 'abc101abc';

$str =~ m/(\d+)/;
print $1 if $1;

print $1 if $str =~ m/(\d+)/;
```